# How to add JavaScript in the content page that inherits from Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages

How to add JavaScript in the content page that inherits from Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage"?

I also need to pass the client IDs of the dropdownlists present on the content in the JavaScript function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish that

1. Master Page. Use the ResolveClientUrl so that your content pages will also be able to resolve the JavaScript location.
2. Content Editor webpart [Sample article](http://mindsharpblogs.com/kathy/archive/2007/11/04/3455.html)
3. [SharePoint (MOSS) Pages: Embedding JavaScript](http://the-north.com/sharepoint/post/Create-Expandable-Regions-in-MOSS-Publishing-Pages.aspx)

Comment: I also need to pass the client IDs of the dropdownlists present on the content in the javascript function.

Comment: feel free to pass them, as JavaScript runs on client side if you use either of mechanism the JavaScript code would be rendered on your content page when page is fully loaded in client browser

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#"         Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microso  ft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyTok  en=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>

Comment: If you see the above code, I can't find the master page for this content page. I wonder how can I find the master page, at first instance

Comment: in publishing layout master page is declared in site definition and then can be changed from the UI so check it from the UI or site definition ghosted copy. Any way i have suggested other two options as well which you can opt if you find first one so hard to impliment